# How to make pack a python script for sharing?

Tags: python

I'm interested in manually packaging my Python script into a compact and sharable Application.

As a self-taught unexperienced semi-programer I have improvised by writing the following **.command**-shell-script and put it in a folder along the rest of the **.py** files from my program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# pip3 install virtualenv
mydir=${0:a:h}
cd $mydir
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install requests
./scripts/a1_v2.command
```

the *a1_v2.command* is my main Python script.
*requests* is the only module my script needs at the moment, but I would like to add more.

Is there a better but also non-complex way to do this?
Or is there a lightweight module I can use?

*More Context:*
I've taught myself Python as a preparation for future career skills in research involving data management and processing. But at my current job I've noticed room for improvement while transferring data about devices we have, between different platforms.
So I wrote a script that reads through Devices' IDs and send a couple of Https-based API request to two platforms, parses through the returned .XML data then sums all devices up in one .XLS list, that's ready for provision then import.

But after presenting the script, my boss asked me to share that program. So I tried different modules that are pretty well advertised. Like Py2App that kept crashing upon installing, and PyInstaller which I couldn't figure out how to make it work with directories.

So I just improvised the above written shell-script.

I'm more interested in knowing how those modules work and in replicating their principles but only to the extends that I need.

Comment: It depends on various things such as the target OS and what applications are installed there. If the target OS has an existing installation of Python (which it seems according to your shell script), then you could simply [create a distribution](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and install it into the virtual environment. This will take case of all dependencies and make your package available within the environment. Also take a look at [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have to invent any wheel ... It was invented.
There is a standard way for packaging your library.

Follow https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

and by the end of the process you will have a library that any onc can install.

Comment: can you show a small example of usage besides the link?

Comment: Sure I can but I do not see any point of doing it since the detailed doc gives a very good cover of the topic. I can copy and paste.. but what is the point of doing that..